# How add object to array jQuery

Tags: jquery, object, each

I'm try add my objects to array, but on finish I have all identical objects

```
$('#Create').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var categoryId = $('#CatId').val();
  var enteredDate = $('#datepicker').val();
  var empId = $('#employeeID').text();
  var systemDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date());
  var obj = {
    CategoryId: categoryId,
    EnteredDate: enteredDate,
    SystemDate: systemDate,
    EmpId: empId
  };
  var arrToServer = [];
  var list = new Array();
  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    var productId = $(this).attr('id');
    obj.ProductId = productId;
    arrToServer.push(obj);                
  });
  arrToServer = JSON.stringify(arrToServer);
}
```

My arrToServer have 2 identical objetcs, why?

Comment: Here's a fiddle that may make the behavior clearer: http://jsfiddle.net/FcHpK/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a copy of object then set project id.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
    var productId = $(this).attr('id');
    var clonedobj = jQuery.extend({}, obj); //create a shallow
    clonedobj.ProductId = productId;
    arrToServer.push(clonedobj);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

> My arrToServer have 2 identical objetcs, why?

Because you are only creating **one** object, outside the  loop, and push the same object to the array multiple times. Passing an object to a function or assigning it to a different variable does not create a copy of the object.

Create the object *inside* the loop (and with loop I mean the `.each` callback).

Here is an example using [`.map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/), which is much cleaner IMO:

```
var arrToServer = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function() {
    return {
        CategoryId: categoryId,
        EnteredDate: enteredDate,
        SystemDate: systemDate,
        EmpId: empId,
        ProductId: $(this).attr('id')
    };
}).get();
```

Comment: Can you please explain why there is a .get() at the end of your example?

Comment: `.get` returns an array. Without it, you would be working with a jQuery object.

Comment: Ah thank you. When I searched, I saw this which referred to Ajax: api.jquery.com/jquery.get. Thanks!